# Connect to RabbitMQ using unix socket

Tags: rabbitmq

Does anyone knows if RabbitMQ supports an unix socket connection instead of TCP ? I ask this because all my producers and consumers are all on the same machine.

Thanks !

Comment: why do you need something other than the connection they provide in the client? speed? reliability?  Is RabbitMQ on the same machine as the producers and consumers?

Comment: Due to speed, and yes the RabbitMQ is on the same machine of the producers and consumers.

Comment: I would like an answer to this question.  I have a producer on the same machine as RabbitMQ, and that producer can only use a Unix socket (not a TCP socket).  Can RabbitMQ monitor an arbitrary Unix socket, and if so, how?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible - RabbitMQ only allows TCP connections[0]. If you really need to use unix sockets I *think* redis allows it over unix socket.

[0] https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html